# Python Mysql: query with possible None values as parameters

Tags: python, mysql, prepared-statement

How can I write query which may contain possible None values as paremeters. Mysql uses IS NULL as operator for NULL values but my query is like

```
SELECT JournalID  FROM Journals WHERE ISSN=?
```

i need to execute the query also if the value for ISSN is NULL changing =? into is null. How could I do that?

EDIT
The question is not simply like "Use OR in where clause". For example:

```
ID  ISSN    TITLE  YEAR
1   null    null   "1990"   
2   "a"     "a"    "1992"
```

I want to get the ID 1 using select. I want to know ONLY that row. How could I do it?
The statement must match in both case, one if I want to retrieve ID 1 (with NULL values) and one if I want to retrieve ID 2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways you can do this

1. Using if and else

```py
if issn == None:
   # SELECT JournalID  FROM Journals WHERE ISSN IS NULL
else:
   # SELECT JournalID  FROM Journals WHERE ISSN = ?
```

2. Writing your prepared statement in the way mentioned below

```sql
SELECT JournalID FROM Journals WHERE ((? IS NULL AND ISSN IS NULL) OR ISSN = ?)
```

I feel the first method is more readable

Comment: I use 11 column as filters in real case, the first solution isn't really doable. I will try second method. Thank you

Comment: Using second method I should double up my parameters but the solution seems to be what I was looking for

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for `OR`?

```
WHERE ISSN IS NULL OR ISSN = ?
```

Comment: It's no simply like that. I Edit my post to explain better my question